# Mark string as safe in Mako

Tags: python, pylons, mako

I'm using Pylons with Mako templates and I want to avoid typing this all the time:

```
${ h.some_function_that_outputs_html() | n }
```

I want to somehow mark the function, or a variable as safe (you can do that in Django) so I don't have to pipe-en all the time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found out that if you put a **html** method in your class, then Mako will just call that method and output whatever it returns in the template.

So I did:

```
def __html__(self):
    return unicode(self)
```

That's basically what h.literal does.

Comment: This has to go into the "class" which is returned by `h.some_function_that_outputs_html()` I assume.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [mako docs about filtering](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/filtering.html), you can set the default filters that are applied inside templates when creating a new `Template` as well as for the `TemplateLookup` (in which case this would apply by default for all the templates that it looks up), with the `default_filters` argument.

Pylons uses this argument with `TemplateLookup` to set the defaults for your project inside the `config/environment.py` file:

```
# Create the Mako TemplateLookup, with the default auto-escaping
config['pylons.app_globals'].mako_lookup = TemplateLookup(
    directories=paths['templates'],
    error_handler=handle_mako_error,
    module_directory=os.path.join(app_conf['cache_dir'], 'templates'),
    input_encoding='utf-8', default_filters=['escape'],
    imports=['from webhelpers.html import escape'])
```

This is why you get the escaping by default (which is not the case when you use Mako by yourself). So you could either change it globally in the config file, or not rely on the standard lookup. Beware that you should of course then explicitly use a filter to escape those things that do need escaping.

You can also pass a string "marked as safe" with the Pylons helper `h.literal`, for example if you would pass `h.literal('This will <b>not</b> be escaped')` to the template, say as a variable named `spam`, you could just use `${spam}` without any escaping.

If you want the same effect when you call a certain function from inside a template, this function would need to return such a literal, or provide a helper for that function that calls `h.literal` on the result if you want to leave the original function alone. (or I guess you could also call it via a "Filtering def" (see same Mako doc as above), haven't experimented with that yet)

Comment: Just a notice for people using the first solution (removing escape from default_filters) - you have to clear cache (rm -r data/templates/*) to see it working (I just spent some wondering what's wrong).