# why can't i display data from a postgres table in html

Tags: python, html, sql, postgresql

hey so i'm storing a string like `'<h1>test</h1><br><br><h1>yep</h1>'` in a table then displaying the result on my webserver, the problem is that the string is exactly that, i'm trying to make it so it will acutally use the h1 tag in the source.

the type of the column i'm storing it in is text, i'm using mako templating system and pyramid web framework

heres what im getting:

[image: what i dont want]

here's what i want it to look like

[image: what i want]

i'm just using a textarea tag to input data into the table.

edit: how i'm adding the string into the db

```
    post_subject = request.params.get("subject")
    post_message = request.params.get("message")
    # some other stuff .....
    cur.execute("\
        INSERT INTO bulbs_Post (subcategory_id, parent_post, title, content, date, user_id, ip) VALUES \
        (%s, %s, %s, %s, now(), %s, %s)", (forum_id, parent_id, post_subject, post_message, user_id, request.client_addr))
```

i'm displaying the content in the template by using `${post_content}`

Comment: </h1>yep</h1>' shouldn't this be <h1>yep</h1>

Comment: yep but it doesn't matter because that was just an example of the kind of data that it receives

Comment: Not nearly enough information here. What web framework are you using? How are you displaying the content? Are you using a templating system - if so which, and show the template.

Comment: 1. Is the correct html text stored in the db? 2. Are you maybe implicitly escaping the text before displaying?

Comment: like i said in the original post i'm using pyramid web framework and mako templating system.

and yes when i look at the column in my sql shell it looks good

Comment: figured it out, mako was escaping it without my knowledge. thanks hans

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825343/mark-string-as-safe-in-mako
this might help.
not posting this as answer because i haven't tried it myself.
please let know if it helps.

Comment: Please don't post answers by editing your question. You can post an answer to your own question which the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alright I have figured it out**, turns out when displaying the content mako was filtering the data anyways. I was able to declare the variable safe using `${post_content | n}`

http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html#turning-off-filtering-with-the-n-filter

Answer (score -1):

Your string is wrong. Use the following string -

```
<h1>test</h1><br><br><h1>yep</h1>
```

Comment: How are you appending the string to the html?

Comment: Considering the raw HTML is being passed through, how did you expect this to help?