# Html string from a variable not rendered using mako in python

Tags: python, html, xml, odoo, mako

When I try to render a string variable in mako template like:
${ variable_name }
As, the variable contains html content, the content is not rendered properly. Rather than displaying HTML, the output just displays the source code like:

```
<div>...<p>..</p>...</div>
```

But the HTML directly written in MAKO renders correctly. Imean

```
var = <p>Not Rendering HTML</p>
Line 1:  <p>Testing line</p>
Line 2:  ${var}
```

Line1 renders as:          `Testing line`

But line 2 renders as:    `<p>Not Rendering HTML</p>`

What should I do...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try outputting your variable with a `n` filter, like so:

```
${var | n}
```

This should disable all default filtering.  You can read more about filtering here:  http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html

You may also want to look at this question and its answers:  [Mark string as safe in Mako](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825343/mark-string-as-safe-in-mako)

Comment: I had tried that, but then it wont execute. Does it require some library or import?

Comment: you saved my day

Comment: Fantastic, just what I needed